# MS 70-536 .NET Framework Foundation - info on Exam? Especially regex?

Tags: regex

I know there are already some questions about this, but not that specific.
I have the self-paced training kit and worked through the test exam tool that is on the CD coming with the book. I constantly fail on the test tool, mostly on the regex questions.

I'm not a regex guru. In fact my regex-fu is more than weak. I know what regex'es are, how I can use them and where my 'Regular expressions - kurz und gut' book is in my drawer in case I really need them. And to be honest I feel like learning regex is a total waste of time, because if I need them I have either a colleague that is fit and can do them in just a few seconds or I need my book and get them right in a still fair amount of time. And from my experience I can tell that I need regex like once in two or three years.

So just putting in a lot of time into learning just the expressions to pass the exam is.. something I like not to have to do.

Can you tell me something about the real exam vs. the test exam tool on the book and about the need to know regex for passing it?

Thank you for your time.

Marked as Community Wiki. Hope that fits?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the content of a specific certification exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the exam won't ask you questions about the regular expression language itself. It is more likely it will ask questions about how to use the Regex and Match classes.

Comment: Well on ome test questions on the cd two answers just differed in the used regex and one of them was right and the other missed two slashes in the regex and was wrong. That's what scared me.

Comment: I haven't seen this kind of question when I did the exam some years ago. Besides, you need a score of 700 to pass the exam, so I think if you miss one question on regular expression usage will not impact your score too much. If you have a good knowledge of the other topics on that exam, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I recently passed the 70-536 exam. The the test questions were quite different from what was on the training CD.But there were absolutely no questions on Regular , Expressions.So I think you are quite safe